# C# Nested Function Wont Trigger

Tags: c#, function

Hello i would like to ask you about a small problem i have with a certain program. So basically the program(console app) reads packets from other Procees(Program) and delivers the packets so they can be analyzed. The problem i stumbeled upon is that One of my nested functions wont trigger (completely). Example:

1. This line is lying in the Main() function. Along with the rest , this is just a clip

   ```
    captureDevice.OnPacketArrival += new       PacketArrivalEventHandler(Program.device_OnPacketArrival);
   ```

After which i have some console.writeline etc. Nothing special.

2. device_OnPacketArrival() is Function with some other Nested Functions Inside.

   ```
    private static void device_OnPacketArrival(object sender, CaptureEventArgs packet)
       {

      DateTime date = packet.Packet.Timeval.Date;
      int length = packet.Packet.Data.Length;
       ..........
       Program.ValidateItem(first_db_id, first_bin_id, out char_id, out user_id, out        type, out valid);
       ............
   ```
3. The Function that causes problem is:ValidateItem()

   ```
    public static void ValidateItem(int item_Id, int item_type, out int char_id, out   int user_id, out int type, out int valid)
   {

       valid = type = user_id  = char_id = 0;

       string oString = "SELECT type,char_id,user_id FROM [DB].[dbo].[Table] WHERE id = @item_id";
       SqlCommand oCmd = new SqlCommand(oString, Program.s_DB);
       oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_id", item_Id);
       try
       {
           using (SqlDataReader oReader = oCmd.ExecuteReader())
           {
               if (oReader.Read())
               {
                   type = Convert.ToInt32(oReader["type"]);
                   char_id = Convert.ToInt32(oReader["char_id"]);
                   user_id = Convert.ToInt32(oReader["user_id"]);
                   if (type == item_type)
                   {
                       valid = 1;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       valid = 0;
                   }

               }

           }
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(ex);

       }

   }
   ```

The Problem is that only the first line of the function is initialized - valid = type = user_id  = char_id = 0; But if i run the function directly in Main() its working fine.

Comment: Your functions aren't "nested". They're just calling each other. To see what's happening in your code, set a breakpoint and step through line by line and see what happens.

Comment: you're kind of leaving us blind here, but my intuition would be to assign your `OnPacketArrival` after everything is ready. Particularly your `Program.s_DB`.

Comment: Ok i just tested something and if i add static constant values to the function it works , but if i use variables such as first_bin_id and first_db_id function wont work correctly which is odd considering they are all int's

Comment: @user2742982 please create a code that can reproduce you problem , and add it to your question (create new application confirm that problem persist and post it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if answering your question 
but in c# there is no "nested" functions , if you need to create that "illusion" try using annonymus 
[functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882516.aspx)

Comment: Correct. Well i shoud not have said nested. My bad , the main on_packetarrive is calling other functions